# How to Use ASP.NET Identity with your own Custom Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have a very simple table that has UserID as int Password as text and Roles as text(comma separated). 
Can i customize ASP.NET Identity structure to use it with my table?

Comment: You have plan text passwords in your database?

Comment: Yes as it is on a local server and security is not a big deal

Comment: That's terrible logic. Passwords should always be hashed.

Comment: Yes I know but till i can use a hashed password using the text field

Comment: No you can't, that's not what a hashed password is!

Comment: any reason for downvoting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can make Identity work with your structure. You'll have to implement `IPasswordValidator` to take whatever hashing (I hope it is hashed) is used for your password. Also you'll have to implement `IUserStore` to point to your table. And `IUserRoleStore` also have to be implemented to take roles from your CSV list.

Here is an overview of the architecture: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity